# Can't connect Snowflake to R Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [Snowflake][ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to connect Snowflake to R. I tried using the following lines of code on R:

```
install.packages(c("DBI", "dplyr","dbplyr","odbc"))
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(odbc)
myconn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "SNOWFLAKEDSII", uid="username", pwd='pwd')
mydata1 <- DBI::dbGetQuery(myconn,"SELECT * FROM mydata")
head(mydata1)
```

When I run the line "myconn" I keep getting this error:

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [Snowflake][ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function.

Could anyone help me figure out how to fix this?

I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: macOS Monterey Version 12.1 Chip Apple M1

Comment: This is a duplicate of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74526126/is-there-a-way-to-connect-snowflake-to-r), can you delete one or the other please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to know where the ODBC driver manager lib is located on your machine. The name of the file: libodbcinst.dylib

You can search it: `find / -iname libodbcinst.dylib`

2. When you've got the path to that file, you need to edit the config file:

   `/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/simba.snowflake.ini`

or it can also be:

`/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/simba.snowflake.ini`

find the line `ODBCInstLib=libodbcinst.dylib` and change it as:
`ODBCInstLib=<full_path_to_the_file>/libodbcinst.dylib`

full_path_to_the_file is the one you found on step 1.

Comment: I couldn't find the file "libodbcinst.dylib" I only have the files "odbc.ini" and "odbcinst.ini"

Comment: looks like something is missed in your ODBC installation. Try to follow the steps from the article: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-create-Snowflake-ODBC-DSN-On-MacOS